# Check if the string contains the substring returns true when its actually false

Tags: python, python-3.x

Is it a problem with my editor or what stupid mistake am I making ? Here is the screen-shot

[image]

This code returns true and it actually should

```
a = "https://www.reddit.com/comments/ado0ym/use_reddit_coins_to_award_gold_to_your_favorite/"
b = "use_reddit_coins_to_award_gold_to_your_favorite"

if b in a:
    print("true")

# Results return true
```

But this must return False but returns True

```
a = "https: // www.reddit.com/comments/ado0ym/"
b = "use_reddit_coins_to_award_gold_to_your_favorite"

if b in a:
    print("true")

# Results return true
```

Comment: The second code you have given is wrong

Comment: There's a quote missing in the second (on line 1).

Comment: The second code works for me... it doesn't print anything

Comment: Try running you code again it works correctly

Comment: your code shouldnt return anything as it is not a function. It should give you an empty console

Comment: here is the screenshot https://i.imgur.com/Az1R2u9.png

Comment: There is only one true that is for the first code. there is nothing in console for second code

Comment: Everything looks good. The program prints once a "True". If your second clause would be true it would print the message twice.

Comment: There is no output for your 2nd command ... use `if b in a: print("true") else: print("Noooope")`

Comment: Try adding an `else` clause to realize that your code is working as expected.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

works fine: First one returns True, second one returns False:

If you're running your code, it should correctly print `true` because the first set is True, and then prints nothing after that:

```
true
```

if both were True, you would see

```
true
true
```

See below:

```
a = "https://www.reddit.com/comments/ado0ym/use_reddit_coins_to_award_gold_to_your_favorite/"
b = "use_reddit_coins_to_award_gold_to_your_favorite"

print (b in a)



a = "https: // www.reddit.com/comments/ado0ym/"
b = "use_reddit_coins_to_award_gold_to_your_favorite"

print (b in a)
```

**Output:**

```
True
False
```

Comment: no idea. all I wanted to do was show the output and then explain her output.

Comment: Before he edited the answer, it wasn't really an answer. Think that's why