# Checking if string contains if either of two substring returns true

Tags: python, python-3.x

Results I get for this code is true but the results are false.Checked in atom code editor and online editor

```
a = "https://www.reddit.com/comments/ado0ym/use_reddit_coins_to_award_gold_to_your_favorite/"
b = "aaaaaaa"
c = "somthing random"

if b or c in a:
    print("true")

else:
    print("false")


# Results return True
```

Comment: in has higher precedence over or, that's all, i.e., you have `if b or (c in a):`

Comment: please try to solve these simple questions yourself, you literally asked a similar question 20 minutes ago --> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54366507/check-if-the-string-contains-the-substring-returns-true-when-its-actually-false

Comment: `if b in a or c in a` is the correct syntax

Comment: @MitchelPaulin this is what I am looking for

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Python doesnt run this code correctly

```
 if b or c in a:
    print("true")
```

The reason is that python percieves this as

```
 if (b) or (c in a):
```

And as if b is always True so code doesnt work as expected

This should be

```
 if (b in a) or (c in a):
    print("true")
```

Hope it helps

Comment: Both the strings are not there. B is also false.

Comment: No if b checks wheather b is there or not and so if b is always true

Comment: @amguruprasath: B isn't false, B is `"use_favorite"`.

Comment: Yep exactly. :)

Comment: ""use_favorite"" does not exist in the string please show me it only has ""your_favorite/""

Comment: i would disagree with you . Hope you dont mind @aws

Comment: @amguruprasath if you write  if b or c in a: python wont check whether b is in a or not it will only check if b exists and it surely does so it always considers this if statement to be True

Comment: ok as you say :)

Comment: okay now b= "aaaaaaaa" i modified the code now it must be false right? but returns true why ?

Comment: @amguruprasath Nope let me explain. The code 'if b or c in a:' is just like 'if (b) or (c in a)' . Note the brackets. The if loop will be true if b is true or c in a is true but when will b be true. Well b will always be true as long as it exists like b="aaaa". . Hope you understand

Answer (score 0):

The problem with your code is the following:

```
if b or c in a:
    print("true")
```

This first checks if b exists. which it does. So it gives True.

What you should do is:

```
if (b in a) or (c in a):
```

Comment: No b is not in c that is the problem. Both the strings are not there.

Comment: It doesn't even check if c is part of a, as that's not needed if b is truthy.

Comment: @amguruprasath: but it doesn't check that b is in a; it checks that b evaluated to True-ish, which it does.

Comment: Both the strings are not there. b is not in a

Comment: it doesnt matter if b is in a or not. That's not what you're checking. You're just checking if b exists.

Comment: "You're just checking if b exists. " but it does not exist and it goes to c to check and it does not exist so the results should be false.

Comment: it does exist. b == "use_favorite"

Comment: ""use_favorite"" does not exist in the string please show me it only has ""your_favorite/""

Comment: You declare it at the start. b = "use_favorite". Line 2. In the if statement you're basicly doing: if (b) or (c in a). c is not part of a so that part is false. But if b is true since b is declared and has a value.

Comment: The problem is that you're never comparing b to a. You're just checking the existance of variable b.

Comment: @vanderZonStef b is false. That is the problem a has ""your fav"" not use_fav

Comment: b is not false. b = "use favorite". Im sorry but really can't explain it any better than this. You should try some basic tutorials about variables and if statements.

Comment: okay now b= "aaaaaaaa" i modified the code now it must be false right? but returns true why ?

Comment: Because b has a different value. The value is "aaaaaaaa". But since it exists it is True.